# Exporting Kiepackage between KieBases

Tags: drools, rule-engine, kie

I have all my functions in a KiePackage in my KieBase. I want to validate a drl file separately for which I am creating a new KieFileSystem and writing the drl content to it and then building it to identify whether there are any errors.

In my drl file, I want to use the functions that are available in a KiePackage in different KieBase. Is there any way where I can import or refer the functions from a different kieBase with the KiePackage name.